# Adding keyboard shortcuts (up, down, enter) to search input suggestions div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search suggestion `div` that appears when you `keyUp` an input. This works fine, but now I am trying to make keyboard shortcuts in action.

I want a behavior like when you click <kbd>down</kbd> keyboard arrow button a `span` gets selected and if it is selected then another `span` that is after gets selected, similarly, if you click <kbd>up</kbd> arrow an upward `span` gets selected, when you click <kbd>enter</kbd> then link opens.

I am stuck because I could not remove a:hover and could not add classes to it. Even after I have basically no idea how to do it. But I really tried hard and a lot..

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DCvUJ/2/) (type anything in field). maybe somebody will help me.

Comment: Under no circumstance, put `[SOLVED]` in the title.  To be most helpful to the community, post the solution as an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should go when the request is made and data is being returned:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        total = 3;
        $(".result-item").mouseenter(
            function(){
                hovered = $(this).attr("id");
                total = 3;

                $(".result-item").each(function(){
                    $(this).children("a").css({
                        'background-color':'#e4e4e4',
                        'color':'#000000'
                    });

                    $(this).find(".searchheading").css({
                            'color':'#191919'
                        });

                    $(this).find(".searchcaption").css({
                        'color':'#555555'
                    });
                });

                $(this).children("a").css({
                    'background-color':'#b7b7b7',
                    'color':'#ffffff'
                });

                $(this).find(".searchheading").css({
                    'color':'#ffffff'
                });

                $(this).find(".searchcaption").css({
                    'color':'#f1f1f1'
                });
            }
        );

    });
</script>
```

And this code on a page where request is made:

```
$("#suggestions").hide();

                $("#search").bind('keyup', function(event){
                    if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 38 || event.which == 13) return false;
                    else
                    {
                        hovered = undefined;
                        lookup($(this).val());
                    }
                });


                $("#search").bind('keydown', 'down', function(evt){
                    if ($("#suggestions").is(":visible"))
                    {
                        if (typeof hovered == 'undefined')
                        {
                            $("#result-item-0").trigger("mouseenter");
                            return;
                        }

                        count = parseInt($("#"+hovered).attr("count"));
                        next = (count + 1);

                        if (next == total)
                            next = 0;

                        $("#result-item-"+next).trigger("mouseenter");
                    }
                });

                $("#search").bind('keydown', 'up', function(evt){
                    if ($("#suggestions").is(":visible"))
                    {
                        if (typeof hovered == 'undefined')
                        {
                            $("#result-item-"+(total-1)).trigger("mouseenter");
                            return;
                        }

                        count = parseInt($("#"+hovered).attr("count"));
                        prev = (count - 1);

                        if (prev == -1)
                            prev = (total-1);

                        $("#result-item-"+prev).trigger("mouseenter");
                    }
                });

                $("#search").bind('keydown', 'return', function(evt){
                    if ($("#suggestions").is(":visible"))
                    {
                        if (typeof hovered == 'undefined')
                        {
                            str = $("#search").val();
                            window.location.href = urlencode(str); // urlencode is a custom function
                            return false;
                        }

                        count = parseInt($("#"+hovered).attr("count"));
                        current = count;
                        $("#result-item-"+current).trigger("mouseenter");

                        $("#suggestions").fadeOut();
                        window.location.href = $("#"+hovered).children("a").attr("href");
                    }
                });

            })
```

;

Also I removed `onkeyup=""` attribute on element, this approach is nicer.